# Changing the comment template in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, comments

So wordpress uses php wp_list_comments();  to go into the wordpress core and fetch comment-template.php to output comments.

As I understand it, editing the wordpress core is a no no, so how does one go about styling the actual comments themselves?
This is only possible so far with CSS, but I want to completely change how they look and for this I'll need to edit the php/html.
The comment-template.php itself is monolithic, writing any semblance of that is frankly, beyond my abilities.

So how can I edit that, or create my own without breaking the wp core?

Comment: Does this page help you out? Looks like you can just define a callback function in your theme to change how the comment renders: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments#Comments_Only_With_A_Custom_Comment_Display

Comment: how about you use disqus comment system? Its the most popular right now. http://disqus.com/admin/wordpress/

Comment: @loQ because I want complete control over it, disqus always seems to look the same.